# What is it all but words!

Tags: meaning

I am reading the novel "Women in love" by D.Lawrence. In it there is coversation between sisters where one asks "But isn't it very risky?" and her sister replies laughingly "What is it all but words!" Can anyone describe what this last line means?

Comment: Words, words ... mere words.

Comment: *It is nothing but words.* --> *It is nothing except words.* --> *It is only words.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context is

> Gudrun knew she was being admired. She sat back from her drawing and looked at Ursula, from under her finely-curved lashes.
>
> “Why did I come back, Ursula?” she repeated. “I have asked myself a thousand times.”
>
> “And don’t you know?”
>
> “Yes, I think I do. I think my coming back home was just *reculer pour mieux sauter.*” (to tense myself in order the better to pounce/leap forwards."
>
> And she looked with a long, slow look of knowledge at Ursula.
>
> “I know!” cried Ursula, looking slightly dazzled and falsified, and as if she did not know. “But where can one jump to?”
>
> “Oh, it doesn’t matter,” said Gudrun, somewhat superbly. “If one jumps over the edge, one is bound to land somewhere.”
>
> “But isn’t it very risky?” asked Ursula.
>
> A slow mocking smile dawned on Gudrun’s face.
>
> “Ah!” she said laughing. “What is it all but words!” And so again she closed the conversation. But Ursula was still brooding.
>
> The "it all" means "life and everything *(the chances, changes, risks and surprises)* that are in it". "But" = except.

Gudrun is being "cool" and sophisticated, as if she were a woman of the world; she is giving the impression of not being concerned by the risks and complications of life, and suggesting that nobody else - i.e. Ursula- should be concerned by them either. Life is only words and words cannot harm you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it means that words are nothing more than that: words.
With this, the sister is asking a rhetorical question, intending to say that once it's just words, they can do no big harm.

Following this line, you could rewrite the question as:

"Are these words something more than just simple words?"

But again, as it seems to be a rhetorical question, she's just trying to show via a question that once they're just words, there's no much damage they can do.

[Edit]

Depending on the context, she could also be trying to devalue the intention of the words. I assumed it consideribg the first line/question.
 For instance, if somebody told her that he/her would do anything for her, she could answer that. And here, she would be asking with a similar intention: these are just words, they mean nothing.

Comment: Gudrun is being cynical and silly. "gun", "bomb" "Coronavirus", "right" and "wrong" are "just words", aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

The context is

> Gudrun knew she was being admired. She sat back from her drawing and looked at Ursula, from under her finely-curved lashes.
>
> “Why did I come back, Ursula?” she repeated. “I have asked myself a thousand times.”
>
> “And don’t you know?”
>
> “Yes, I think I do. I think my coming back home was just *reculer pour mieux sauter.*” (to tense myself in order the better to pounce/leap forwards."
>
> And she looked with a long, slow look of knowledge at Ursula.
>
> “I know!” cried Ursula, looking slightly dazzled and falsified, and as if she did not know. “But where can one jump to?”
>
> “Oh, it doesn’t matter,” said Gudrun, somewhat superbly. “If one jumps over the edge, one is bound to land somewhere.”
>
> “But isn’t it very risky?” asked Ursula.
>
> A slow mocking smile dawned on Gudrun’s face.
>
> “Ah!” she said laughing. “What is it all but words!” And so again she closed the conversation. But Ursula was still brooding.
>
> The "it all" means "life and everything *(the chances, changes, risks and surprises)* that are in it". "But" = except.

Gudrun is being "cool" and urbane; she is giving the impression of not being bothered by the risks and complications of life - Life is only words and words cannot harm you.